# Insert customer field to custom object

Tags: php

I am trying to insert a customer object into a custom object called Vouchers.
I am fetching the object using:

```
$customer_object = $this->apiCall("sobjects/Customers__c/someid", array(), 'GET');
```

Further down in the code I am trying create the object using:

```
$params['Customer__c'] = $customer_object;
$salesforce_object->objectCreate('Vouchers__c',$params);
$this->apiCall("sobjects/Customers__c", $params, 'POST');
```

This throws an Error:

```
Cannot deserialize instance of reference from START_OBJECT value { at [line:1, column:165]
```

How can I pass the customer object as a param?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that when you need to enter and object as aa reference you just enter it's ID.